# Getting error for basic Eland example (loading index from a locally installed ELK docker container)

Tags: elasticsearch, elk, eland

We installed ELK in docker based on [this example](https://gist.github.com/ionutale/2862aa94f7c72bd9e77cd2f239172efd). Like:

```
docker run -d --name elasticsearchdb --net es-stack-network -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:6.8.13

docker run -d --name kibana-es-ui --net es-stack-network -e "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearchdb:9200" -p 5601:5601 kibana:6.8.13
```

We then set up Elastic with the basic built-in data sets, including the flights dataset offered by default.

Then we tried using [Eland](https://community.elastic.co/events/details/elastic-emea-virtual-presents-introduction-into-eland-a-python-package-to-analyse-explore-and-manipulate-elasticsearch-data/) to pull that data into a dataframe, and I think we're following the [documentation](https://eland.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/eland.DataFrame.html#eland.DataFrame) correctly.

But with the code:

```
    import eland as ed
    index_name = 'flights'
    ed_df = ed.DataFrame('localhost:9200', index_name)
```

we get this error:

```
File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\elastic_transport\client_utils.py:198, in url_to_node_config(url)
    192     raise ValueError(f"Could not parse URL {url!r}") from None
    194 if any(
    195     component in (None, "")
    196     for component in (parsed_url.scheme, parsed_url.host, parsed_url.port)
    197 ):
--> 198     raise ValueError(
    199         "URL must include a 'scheme', 'host', and 'port' component (ie 'https://localhost:9200')"
    200     )
    202 headers = {}
    203 if parsed_url.auth:

ValueError: URL must include a 'scheme', 'host', and 'port' component (ie 'https://localhost:9200')
```

So when we add `http://`, like so:

```
    import eland as ed
    index_name = 'flights'
    ed_df = ed.DataFrame('http://localhost:9200', index_name)
```

We get this error:

```
File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\elastic_transport\_node\_http_urllib3.py:199, in Urllib3HttpNode.perform_request(self, method, target, body, headers, request_timeout)
    191         err = ConnectionError(str(e), errors=(e,))
    192     self._log_request(
    193         method=method,
    194         target=target,
   (...)
    197         exception=err,
    198     )
--> 199     raise err from None
    201 meta = ApiResponseMeta(
    202     node=self.config,
    203     duration=duration,
   (...)
    206     headers=response_headers,
    207 )
    208 self._log_request(
    209     method=method,
    210     target=target,
   (...)
    214     response=data,
    215 )

ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))))
```

So I thought, well, maybe it's serving on HTTPS by default for some reason, maybe not related but in the logs I saw:

```
05T17:17:04.734Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.18.0.3:9200, remoteAddress=/172.18.0.1:59788}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[21683dc12cff][transport_worker][T#14]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"XuzqXMk_QgShA3L5HnfXgw","elasticsearch.node.id":"H1CsKboeTyaFFjk2-1nw2w","elasticsearch.node.name":"21683dc12cff","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
```

so I try replacing `http` with `https` and get this error:

```
TlsError: TLS error caused by: TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)))
```

So I look up this error and find [this thread](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/712) which says do something like:

```
import ssl
from elasticsearch.connection import create_ssl_context

ssl_context = create_ssl_context(<use `cafile`, or `cadata` or `capath` to set your CA or CAs)
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

es = Elasticsearch('localhost', ssl_context=context, timeout=60
```

But this isn't helpful because Eland handles `elasticsearch` instancing internally, I'm not controlling that.

This is a very basic scenario, so I'm sure the solution must be much simpler than all this. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

For who ever is still struggling, the following worked for me with a local Elastic cluster using Docker/docker-compose:

[Following this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) you'd have the http_ca.crt file locally, using the command:

```
docker cp es01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt .
```

You can use the http_ca.crt file when creating your es_client:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es_client = Elasticsearch("https://localhost:9200",
                          ca_certs="/path/to/http_ca.crt",
                          basic_auth=("[elastic username]",
                                      "[elastic password]"))
```

And then use the es_client to connect to eland:

```
import eland as ed
df = ed.DataFrame(es_client=es_client, es_index_pattern="[Your index]")
df.head()
```